# How to make kaminari work across multiple ajax paginations

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari

my show.js.erb code

```
<% if @status = "answered"%>
  $('#all_answered').html('<%= escape_javascript render(partial: "trackers/all_answered") %>');
  $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@answered, :remote => true,:param_name => "all_answered").to_s) %>');
<% else %>
  $('#all_questions').html('<%= escape_javascript render(partial: "trackers/all_questions") %>');
  $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@all_questions, :remote => true,:param_name => "all_questions").to_s) %>');
<% end %>
```

view

```
<div id="paginator">
   <%= paginate @answered, :remote => true, :param_name => "all_answered" %>
 </div>
 <div id="all_answered">
   <%= render partial: "all_answered" %>
 </div>
```

controller

```
@answered = Tracker.where("user_id = ? AND answered = ?", current_user, true).page(params[:all_answered]).per(1)
if(params[:all_answered])
      @status = "answered"
    end
```

in my view i also have a similar pagination for another part of the same page. The problem is when i click on one, the other one gets triggered as well and they get mixed up. how can i separate them?

Answer (score 0):

When you say they get "triggered as well... and get mixed up" what do you mean?

To include multiple paginations in one page uniquely name the param_name: as it seems you have done from your show.js.erb. ie. :all_answered and :all_questions.

In your show.js.erb should your conditional be changed?

```
<% if @status = "answered"%> to <% if @status == "answered"%>
```

Lastly, provided this doesn't impact other code, consider testing the params argument directly rather then setting an instance variable in the controller.
ie.

```
<% unless params[:all_answered].blank? %>
```